# Do a header("refresh") only 1x.

Tags: php

I am using PHP and got the following code:

```
header("refresh:30;url=".$autoDownloadLink);
```

It starts an auto download after 30 seconds by redirecting to a page, I want it to only do this 1x.

I can't use Javascript or add any code to the page that this code redirect too since the page stored in $autoDownloadLink variable is another party.

Comment: What does "I want it to only do this 1x." mean?

Comment: it need to only refresh it once then never ever again, my code will do the refresh every 30 seconds.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Like this:

```
header("refresh:0;url=".$autoDownloadLink);
```